# Why the Linux command cp is not zero-copy?

Tags: linux, copy, posix, system-calls, cp

I use strace to trace command `cp a.txt b.txt`.

It shows that it copied the file using read and write syscall.

But there are some zero-copy syscall like sendfile, splice.
Although splice does not support file-to-file data copy.

Why does not the command cp using those syscall (so we don't have to copy data to userspace)?

Comment: [These lines](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/06f70d9ee69163fb2b18647963d6d6e81b6bd35d/TODO#L54) were committed in 2003.

Comment: (戴均維: If your question receives a answer you like don't forget to accept it (or comment on why it doesn't answer your question))

Answer (score 3):

You answered your own question: `sendfile()` does not support file-to-file operation.

> Why does not the Linux kernel provide a syscall which performs file to file data copy with zero-copy?

Probably because nobody has a use case where it improves performance by that much or in a way that doesn't have bad trade-offs.  All you can really do is have a single syscall arrange both the DMA from disk to RAM and from RAM to disk, instead of two syscalls as you have now.  If this reduction is syscalls matters to you, look at io_uring: https://vorner.github.io/2019/11/03/io-uring-mental-experiments.html (a very new feature, so you can't expect to see it used in `cp` yet).

People who care a lot about file copy performance often use copy-on-write to avoid copying in the first place, and/or break their files into multiple pieces so they only need to copy or modify one piece instead of a huge file.

Comment: Imagine the impact on the environment if people actually treated CPUs respectfully by bringing the use of sendfile, even with known caveats, into a copy utility, or better yet, io-uring since it's in v5.1 and most distros now have default kernels above that... but apparently there's no use case for it.

Answer (score 0):

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html

> In Linux kernels before 2.6.33, out_fd must refer to a socket.
> Since Linux 2.6.33 it can be **any file**.  If it is a regular file,
> then sendfile() changes the file offset appropriately.

Comment: How does the quote you gave answer the question?

Comment: @ShaneBishop It shows that sendfile can be used for that purposes (Why does not the Linux kernel provide a syscall which performs file-to-file data copy with zero-copy?)